# OMXPlayer not exiting after playing mp3

Tags: omxplayer, nfs

I suddenly ran into this problem. My default OMXPlayer is not exiting ("hanging") after playing a .mp3 from the command line. The only way to exit is Ctrl Z, so I can't use any sort of loop function for a playlist. My songs are played from a networked NAS directory using NFS mount. I tried to un- and remount again, hide error messages ( > dev/null) and to set the timeout to 1 second (--timeout) without success.

The setup and command line worked perfectly a few days ago. Now I can't even get OMXPlayer to exit normally even after only trying to play one song:

`omxplayer -o local --timeout 1 "/mnt/song.mp3"`

Any ideas what can be wrong?

Comment: Same thing happens with me. I think it's just the way omxplayer works. If you want, since it's open source, you can edit the code yourself.